# Can't start mysqld anymore after try restart it

Tags: timeout, centos5, mysql, federated

I try to search for whole day but nothing make it work.
First time ,after type "service mysqld restart" and wait for too long time. It announce service mysqld stop but nothing happened after that , so i press Ctrl + C and try restart again and wait and then this happened

Here is log file
I can't post images . here is the link of image
[enter link description here](http://pik.vn/201469748136-5063-4a97-a399-40455362f220.jpeg)

OR any solution to backup all databases when mysqld not running .

Comment: backup database! call supporter and tell him restart mysql :3

Answer (score 2):

Stop interrupting your server, and read the log;

You see where it says "database was not shut down normally!" and "Starting crash recovery."

It's *trying* to recover from a crash or an improper shutdown.  Go further back in the log and you may see the original incident, but for now, the answer is to stop interrupting it and let it recover.

Once that happens, it will tell you, via the log, when it is ready to start accepting connections again... or if it's unable to recover, the log will tell you that crash recovery has failed,  in no uncertain terms.

Don't use `kill -9` unless you (a) really know what you are doing and (b) are prepared for further data corruption.  That's a very heavy-handed approach and should not be used lightly, particularly when the server has already told you exactly what's going on.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
ps -ef | grep mysqld
```

the second number from the left is the process-id, run:

```
kill -9 <process-id>
```

and then try to start it again.

Comment: Still not make it work http://pik.vn/20140aeeb146-9622-4074-a768-b160e3bf5d2c.jpeg